# Multiple namespaces on ActiveAdmin [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm using [active_admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) and having issues setting up multiple namespaces.

config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "One Driver"
  config.site_title_link = "/"
  config.default_namespace = :admin

  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.site_title = "superadmin"
    admin.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
    admin.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
    admin.logout_link_path = :destroy_admin_user_session_path
  end

  config.namespace :control do |control|
    control.authentication_method = :authenticate_company!
    control.current_user_method = :current_company
    control.logout_link_path = :destroy_company_session_path
    control.comments = false
  end
end
```

app/admin/dashboard:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard", namespace: :admin do
  ...
```

app/control/dashboard.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard", namespace: :control do
  ...
```

app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_for :companies, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  ...
```

When I visited /control, it is redirected to /admin
How can I fix it?

Comment: can you please show `active_admin` routes currently being generated?

Comment: fumiya did you fix this?

Comment: Same problem, have you fix?

Comment: any update on this one?